# What is better way to get difference of two lists?

Tags: python

There is in one directory where every time new files are generated, like some log files.

My purpose is to get an amount of file generated during 10 mins. To get such value real time.data is as follow:

```
00:00 ~ 00:10        10 files

00:10 ~ 00:20        23 files

...

23:50 ~ 23:59        12 files
```

So my idea is to run statistics script every 10 mins by crontab task on Linux system.
Logic the 1st time run script: get current file list by `glob.glob("*")`.

Let me say A, so when script run next time (after 10 mins), it will run `glob` again to get current file list B. I need different value which in B. no A. so I can get amount.
How to do? If you have another good way, please share.

Comment: for i in B:
    for j in A:
        XXXX
need two loop, but i hope to get other better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to look into [sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set).  You can do something like:

```
setA = set(listA)
setB = set(listB)
new_list = list(setB - setA)
```

You can also do additional set logic to identify files that are deleted and such.

Comment: +1 Sets are a good way to approach the problem. In addition the script will have to save the current set and read it back in the next time it is run in order to have something to compare with the current set of files.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented on @tcaswell's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13420585/355230), using Python's built-in set class is an excellent way to solve a problem like this. Here's some sample code loosely based on Tim Golden's Python Stuff article [*Watch a Directory for Changes*](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html):

```
import os

firstime = False
path_to_watch = '.'

try:
    with open('filelist.txt', 'rt') as filelist:
        before = set(line.strip() for line in filelist)
except IOError:
    before = set(os.listdir(path_to_watch))
    firstime = True

if firstime:
    after = before
else:
    after = set(os.listdir(path_to_watch))
    added = after-before
    removed = before-after
    if added:
        print 'Added: ', ', '.join(added)
    if removed:
        print 'Removed: ', ', '.join(removed)

# replace/create filelist
with open('filelist.txt', 'wt') as filelist:
    filelist.write('\n'.join(after) + '\n')
```